# JS periodic update of svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've been trying to do animations with svgs. I am testing this set up here:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<svg id="svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
</svg>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var svg = document.getElementById("svg");

        var rect = document.createElement("rect");
        rect.setAttribute("id", "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("y", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("height", "50");
        rect.setAttribute("width", "50");

        svg.appendChild(rect);

        setInterval(function(){
            var r = document.getElementById("rect");
            (r.getAttribute("height") == "50") ? r.setAttribute("height", "60") : r.setAttribute("height", "50")
        }, 2000);
</script>


</body></html>
```

And the source of the page does change as expected, fluctuating between the two height values every 2 seconds:

```
<rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" height="50" width="50"></rect>
```

```
<rect id="rect" x="50" y="50" height="25" width="50"></rect>
```

But these updates do not show on the page. In fact, nothing shows. Any pointers appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) instead of `createElement`

Comment: I saw something like that, and found that svg name space is http://www.w3.org/2000/svg but couldnt find something similar for rect. Do you know what it is or where I can find it?

Comment: It's the first line in the page you've just linked.

Comment: Yeah turns out it is still w3.org/2000/svg for rects too.

@enxaneta your suggestion of using create/get/setNS did the trick. I'm trying to understand why this works and the method I tried doesn't. Why's that?

Comment: Please read this: [Namespaces crash course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)

Answer (score 0):

Right now it just says svg instead of document.getElementById("svg") on line svg.appendChild(rect);.

This may be the cause of your error as a child element cannot be appended to NULL.

**Change svg.appendChild(rect); to:**

document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(rect);

OR

**Add a line that defines svg:**

svg = document.getElementById("svg");

Comment: My Apologies, i pasted earlier code. I checked the console the saw the error you mention and added that line. The issue is still there as I mention the rect does get added to the svg and the element's attributes do change every 2 seconds. I updated the question